# Is the alternating sequence Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

How can I show that $a_n$ = $(-1)^n$ is Cauchy?

I know that a definition of Cauchy is $\forall$ $\epsilon$ > 0, $\exists$ $N \in$ $\mathbb N$ such that if $x,y$ $\ge$ $N$, then $|a_x - a_y|$ < $\epsilon$.

This was my informal attempt.

We know that x,y can either be even or odd. If x and y are both even and greater than 0, then $|a_x - a_y|$ = 0, which is not less than 0. Therefore no such $N$ exists, and $a_n$ = $(-1)^n$ is Cauchy?  is not Cauchy.

Comment: You can’t: it isn’t. No tail of the sequence has diameter less than $2$.

Comment: counter example: whatever $N$ is, let $x\geq N$ and $y:=x+1$. (given $\epsilon <2$)

Comment: Re-write your def'n of Cauchy by replacing the words "such that if " with "$\forall$", And delete the word "then".. Note the effect of  "$\forall x,y \geq N$"  has on the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove that $\left \{ a_{n} \right \}_{n\geq 0}\ $ is NOT Cauchy:

To do this we must find an $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $N>0$ there are integers $m,n\ \geq N$ with the property that $\vert a_n-a_m\vert >\epsilon$.

So we set $\epsilon =1$ and let $N>0$ be given.

Now we just observe that if $n=N+1$ and $m=N,\ $then $\vert (-1)^{N+1}-(-1)^N\vert =2>\epsilon$ and we are done.